# Exporting schema to a XML database

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xquery

I am working on a Java program that connects to a databases and serves as a design and data manipulation tool. I eventually want to port my program to an XML database of some kind.

More specifically, I want to be able to use Java to upload XSD (representing a database) that I generate to an actual XML database (like Sedna) and then connect to this database and query/update it.

I have been exploring Sedna and the XQJ API and I don't see how to do this. Can it be done through Java?

**Edit** I don't have any data I want to map to XML or a database. I have a database structure specified in XSD, and I just want to create the corresponding database on a server somewhere.

Comment: If you use a schema-free database, then you can just store the XML as you have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two frameworks worth trying for XML to database mapping:

- Castor XML http://www.castor.org
- Hibernate http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I don't think this is exactly what I am looking for. I will update my question.